# How to copy select files from subfolders to a single folder based on file paths saved in excel?

Tags: r, file-copying

I have a folder with several subfolders containing maybe 10,000 files and I'm interested in pulling out specific files with those different subfolders. I know which files I want pulled out, the file names and paths are saved in an excel file but I keep getting errors that I can't figure out how to navigate around.

```
file.copy(file.path(Relevant$FilePath), new_location)
```

- Relevant = excel file with file path of select files
- FilePath = column header containing the file path for each individual file
- New_location = folder I'm trying to move the files to

I've tried copying the files to different location and get one of two errors. The first is

```
In file.copy(file.path(Relevant$FilePath), new_location) :
  problem copying H:\Outputs\test1.wav to C:\Box\new_location\test1.wav: No such file or directory
```

Another error I see is

```
Error in file.copy(file.path(Relevant$FilePath), new_location) : 
  more 'from' files than 'to' files
```

Comment: Can you share some of these values (paste the output of `head(Relevant$FilePath)`, `head(new_location)` to your question)? Also, what does `file.exists("H:\\Outputs\\test1.wav")` return if you enter it in your console?

Comment: Try removing `file.path`. If the Excel file contains the qualified file names, it's probably not needed and its use can be an error. I know this example is not the best but check the output of `file.path("./Temp/", "Temp2")`.

Comment: I tried to remove `file.path`, but still get the error `more 'from' files than 'to' files`.

Comment: `head(MR.relevant$FilePath)
[1] "D:\\Outputs\\SU23_20230601_030841_000.wav"
[2] "D:\\Outputs\\SU23_20230528_031844_000.wav"
[3] "D:\\Outputs\\SU23_20230524_035137_000.wav"`

Comment: `head(new_location)
[1] "D:\test"`

Comment: `file.exists("D:\\Outputs\\SU23_20230601_030841_000.wav")
[1] TRUE`